# How to find out this limit of sequence $ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^{n}}{ e^{n}}$ By L'Hopital

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do i find limit of this sequence . I have tried L'Hopital . But coudnt do it .Any hints ? Thanks .

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^{n}}{ e^{n}}$$

Answer (score 5):

For $n>5$, we have $\left(\dfrac{n}e\right)^n > 2^n$. Now conclude what you want.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^n}{e^n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n}{e} \right)^n$$
$$y=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n}{e} \right)^n$$
$$\ln y=\lim_{n \to \infty} \ln\left(\frac{n}{e} \right)^n$$
$$\ln y=\lim_{n \to \infty} n\ln\left(\frac{n}{e} \right)$$
$$\ln y=\lim_{n \to \infty} n\ln n - n \ln e$$
$$\ln y=\lim_{n \to \infty} n\ln n - n$$
$$\ln y=\lim_{n \to \infty} (n)(\ln n - 1)$$
Can you go from here?

Comment: Thanks. in your last step its becoming $\infty$$/0$ form . how to deal with that  .

Comment: Here you go. . .

Comment: How can u use L'Hopital in this case ?

Comment: I differentiated the top ($\ln x -1$) and the bottom ($\frac{1}{x}$). . .

Comment: But its $\infty$$/0$ form

Comment: $n^{-1} \times -n^{-(-2)}=$. . . ?

Comment: I am asking about step u did before applying L'hopital ..As far i know it can be applied to 0/0 and infinity/infinity forms

Comment: Ah, I think I was wrong in doing that.

Comment: If you ever get a $\lim g(x)/f(x)=\infty/0$ form, just rewrite it as $\lim g(x)\cdot (1/f(x))=\infty\cdot\infty$.  Which doesn't require L'Hopital to evaluate.

Comment: @Bye_World Yep, I realized that after I made the second edit.